# Incorrect serial SSD number

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to get manufacturer serial number of physical drives.

I'm trying to get it this way (the code works pretty good with HDD, but returns incorrect serial number, something like this `0000_0000_0100_0000_E4D2_5C42_46E3_4D01`):

```
// there I get handle to physical drive
// HANDLE h = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", FILE_ANY_ACCESS , FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
// bool success = h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
std::string getSerialNumber(HANDLE h)
{


    std::string result;
    static STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY spq = { StorageDeviceProperty, PropertyStandardQuery };
    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PSTR psz;
        PSTORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR psdd;
    };
    ULONG size = sizeof(STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR) + 0x100;
    ULONG dwError;
    do
    {
        dwError = ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES;
        if (buf = LocalAlloc(0, size))
        {
            DWORD returned;
            if (DeviceIoControl(h, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, &spq, sizeof(spq), buf, size, &returned, 0))
            {
                if (psdd->Version >= sizeof(STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR))
                {
                    if (psdd->Size > size)
                    {
                        size = psdd->Size;
                        dwError = ERROR_MORE_DATA;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (psdd->SerialNumberOffset)
                        {
                            result = psz + psdd->SerialNumberOffset;
                            dwError = NOERROR;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw std::runtime_error(std::to_string(ERROR_NO_DATA));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw std::runtime_error(std::to_string(ERROR_GEN_FAILURE));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw std::runtime_error(std::to_string(GetLastError()));
            }

            LocalFree(buf);
        }
    } while (dwError == ERROR_MORE_DATA);
    return result;
}
```

So the question is do I use API correct way? If someone know how to get a serial number another way I'll glad to see it.

**Edit:** 
I also tried to use WMI.

Linux and UEFI enviroment show correct results, at Windows I couldn't achieve it.

Comment: why you think that `0000_0000_0100_0000_E4D2_5C42_46E3_4D01` is incorrect ? this is what device return to you. and what is "correct" you think ?

Comment: also, not related to concrete result, if you `throw` - who will call `LocalFree(buf);` ?

Comment: @RbMm I think that this number is incorrect because it shows different result from linux and uefi (linux and uefi shows the same results).
on linux I do it this way: `udevadm info -q all -n /dev/nvme0n1 | grep SERIAL`

Comment: but if windows return this string to you - what you want ? [SerialNumberOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-_storage_device_descriptor) - *Specifies the byte offset from the beginning of the structure to a null-terminated ASCII string that contains the device's product revision string. If the device has no product revision string, this member is zero.*

Comment: @RbMm, I want to get the same number that I get from UEFI and Linux. It also doesn't work with USB (for some devices I get `123456781234567812345678`) - it does'nt looks like serial number, but UEFI and Linux returns same results.

Comment: @RbMm I'll try to explain, why do I need it: I have UEFI and Linux application, it serialize data in some format, now I need Windows application, so I need to compare this data with data on my machine

Comment: if `SerialNumberOffset` not zero, this is what driver return for you for this device object. this string is returned by driver (if it not empty).

Comment: you can try for test `wmic diskdrive get serialnumber` from cmd. are you got the same results ?

Comment: can for concrete device `wmic path win32_diskdrive where deviceid='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE<N>' get serialnumber` where in place `<N>` 0, 1, .. or another device path - look in winobj

Comment: @RbMm, yes, I tried it. As written in question: *Edit: I also tried to use WMI.*.
Just tried `wmic path win32_diskdrive where deviceid='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE<N>' get serialnumber`. Return: `0000_0000_0100_0000_E4D2_5C42_46E3_4D01`

Comment: > if SerialNumberOffset not zero, this is what driver return for you for this device object. this string is returned by driver (if it not empty)

Get it. Thank you for help! Don't you know any way to resolve this problem? (if it doesn't assume writing my own driver)

Comment: so result the same as in your code. simply windows return this string as serial

Comment: @АлександрЩетнев What is the correct result (what do you get on Linux)?

Comment: @mnistic, `BTPY72960UBX128A`

Comment: `udevadm` can be [flaky sometimes](https://serverfault.com/q/844109), try with `hdparm` on Linux.